# Сложности с JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

Подключил JSTL в Maven, но при запуске получаю

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:590)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:426)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:198)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:414)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:59)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:193)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:414)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

код pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Farma_last_tochno</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Farma_last_tochno</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Код моей index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search" method="get">
    <label>Введите ваш запрос
        <input type="text" name = "serach">
        <input type="submit"
        value="Send">
    </label>

    <jsp:useBean id="Model" class="com.example.Farma_last_tochno.Model"/>

    <jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="*"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="name"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="price"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="count"/>

    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${Model.name.size()}" step="i">
        <c:forEach items="#{Model.name}" var="nameItem">
            <c:out value="${nameItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:forEach items="#{Model.count}" var="countItem">
            <c:out value="${countItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:forEach items="#{Model.price}" var="priceItem">
            <c:out value="${priceItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>

        <c:forEach items="#{Model.nameRecipe}" var="nameRecipeItem">
            <c:out value="${nameRecipeItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:forEach items="#{Model.countRecipe}" var="countRecipeItem">
            <c:out value="${countRecipeItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:forEach items="#{Model.priceRecipe}" var="priceRecipeItem">
            <c:out value="${priceRecipeItem}"/>
        </c:forEach>

    </c:forEach>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите что я неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема!

Решение - я **загрузила jar-файлик и положила его в WEB-INF/lib**, остальной мавен не трогала. Так, конечно, идея не видит эту библиотеку и потому не сможет предоставить автодополнение, но тем не менее работает